# How can I disable incoming remote desktop connections while I run an "outgoing" remote desktop session?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

**The setup:**
I have an office PC running Windows XP. However, I usually have to work at (i.e., be physically present at) various labs, where there are lab PCs. In order to still have all my programs and scripts available, I open a remote desktop connection from the lab PC to the office PC.

**The problem:**
The lab PCs are shared between many users, and sometimes co-workers open a remote desktop session to them. If I am running a full-screen remote session from the lab PC to my office PC at that moment, then the co-worker unkowingly lands on the desktop of my Office PC, and hilarity ensues.

**The temporary work-around:**
I tend to disable incoming remote connections while I am at the lab PCs. (Right click on "Workspace", choose the "Remote" tab, unclick the "Allow incoming Remote connections" checkbox). However, I also tend to forget to re-enable them, which makes my co-workers unhappy.

Is there any better solution? A permament setting that disallows "forwarding" of the remote desktop session? Or a script, maybe, that disables incoming remote desktop connections while the outgoing connection is active?

Comment: In one line.. you want to restrict a single person access to the remote desktop at a single time. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Pradip: I am not sure I understand your question. In one line: On the shared machine (in the lab) that I am sitting in front of, I want to disable "incoming" RDP connections for as long as I have an "outgoing" RDP connection (to my personal work PC) active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable and disable "Remote desktop" in a script you can use the following:

To disable:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

To enable:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

If you use it in a batch file like this it works:
This will prevent anyone from connecting to **your** Office-pc on which you started "Remote Desktop" to a Lab-pc)

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
start /wait mstsc.exe
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

You could also specify to which host you want to connect starting `mstsc.exe`.

However, you **do** need to run this as administrator. (Right-click and `Run as administrator`)

If you want to disable new connection to the machine you're taking over (the Lab-pc's) you need to add some of these commands to the `taskmanager` to execute on remote logon and logoff. But as I understood it you want to disable it on your Office-Pc while connecting to the Lab-pc for which you can use this batch file.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I want to connect from the lab PC to my office PC, but fortunately I have administrator rights on all Lab PCs. The script runs great, I don't even need to `Run as administrator`. (We really should review our IT security policies...) Thanks!

Comment: Aaa, yes. It's XP. There, if you have administrator rights, you don't have to `Run as administrator`. That's only with Windows Vista and higher.